# cakePHP - make a default current year in index.ctp

Tags: cakephp

I newbie in cakePHP.
I has some problem on display default current year in index.ctp
This code of index.ctp.

```
<?php 
    echo $html->tableCells  (array  (array  ('Course', 
                                            $form->select('id',$courses)
                                            ),

                                    array   ('Location', 
                                            $form->select('id',$locations)
                                            ),
                                    array   ('Month', 
                                            $form->month('mob')
                                            ),
                                    array   ('Year', 
                                            $form->year('year',2011,2012)
                                            ),

                                    )
                            );
```

?>

Thank you for your advanced :)

Answer (score 0):

Try `$form->year('year',2011,2012, date('Y'))`